# Change Avada fusion_portfolio_grid_title HTML markup

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently trying to change der Avada portfolio grid title markup. Right now it is wrapped in `<h2>` tags, but I want it to be a plain `<a>` tag. I found the `fusion_portfolio_grid_title` filter, but I really dont get it to work. What I tried:

```
add_filter( 'fusion_portfolio_grid_title', 'change_grid_title');
function change_grid_title() {
    $post_title = '<a>' $post_title '</a>';
    return = $post_title;
};
```

Can somebody help out?

Answer (score 0):

```
function change_grid_title( $post_title ) {
    $post_title = strip_tags($post_title, '<a></a>');
    return $post_title;
};
add_filter( 'fusion_portfolio_grid_title', 'change_grid_title');
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.